# customizing print method for wrapper classes

Tags: java, collections

I have small piece of code which is giving me out like [1, 2, 3], but can we modify this into {1@2@3} or any other format.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Integer> mySet  = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Integer i1=1;
        Integer i2=2;
        Integer i3=3;
        mySet.add(i1); 
        mySet.add(i2);
        mySet.add(i3);
        System.out.println(mySet);
    }
```

Comment: I fail to see the question

Comment: You can’t modify an existing declaration, but you can declare your own, or use `String` manipulation.

Comment: @Mark they appear to want to modify the format of the `String` returned from `toString()`.

Comment: You can anonimize your `HashSet` and override its `toString` implementation, print your own version with some utility method, etc. etc.

Comment: The clean way to not violate the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) would be to write a custom `HashMapFormatter`-class that takes a `HashMap` and returns a `String`-representaiton of the given `HashMap`.

Comment: you can't modify it directly as toString method is defined and that implementation is coming from JDK though you can create your own custom Set implementation and you can define your own representation of toString method or if you dont want implement your own set, just iterate over set and create structure you need.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

System.out.println(mySet);
Method println() is basically working with toString() for any object except some exceptions,so when we are passing the collection type of object inside this method it calling the toString() method of that related collection, like in your case it is HashSet.java but this class having toString() inherited method of AbstractCollection.java, if we check that method it is looking like:

```
 public String toString() {
        Iterator<E> it = iterator();
        if (! it.hasNext())
            return "[]";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append('[');
        for (;;) {
            E e = it.next();
            sb.append(e == this ? "(this Collection)" : e);
            if (! it.hasNext())
                return sb.append(']').toString();
            sb.append(',').append(' ');
        }
    }
```

So you have to override this method according to your requirements.

Comment: Too verbose and inefficient. With just a line and stream you can solve that!

Comment: "*...for any object except some exceptions...*" - May I ask for an example of those exceptions?

Comment: here exceptions doesn't mean java exceptions, I am referring  different arguments of println() method so that depending on that it will call the related method.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use

```
System.out.printf("{%s}\n", mySet.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("@")));
```

to get the result you want.

To retain this format for the created `Set`, you can use this to put into the override of `toString()` people are talking about:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Set<Integer> mySet  = new HashSet<Integer>() {
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("{%s}", stream().collect(Collectors.joining("@")));
        }
    }
    Integer i1=1;
    Integer i2=2;
    Integer i3=3;
    mySet.add(i1); 
    mySet.add(i2);
    mySet.add(i3);
    System.out.println(mySet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can parse it toString and modifies it.

eg.

```
public static<T> String modifier(Set<T> input, String begin, String separator, String end) {
    return input.toString()
                .replace("[", begin)
                .replace(", ", separator)
                .replace("]", end);
   }
```

And then call:

```
System.out.println(modifier(mySet, "{", "@", "}"));
```

Of course you can remove all params and make it as defualt:

```
    public static<T> String modifier(Set<T> input) {
    return input.toString()
                .replace("[", "{")
                .replace(", ", "@")
                .replace("]", "}");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a functional solution for `Java 8`.

You can build a `stream` that execute `toString` and then join all together using `collect`.

```
"[" + mySet.stream().map(i -> Integer.valueOf(i)).collect(Collectors.joining(",")) + "]"
```

Answer (score 0):

The of  `System.out.println(mySet);` will call `mySet.toString()` and the implementation which will be used is the one of `AbstractCollection` which gives something like `[1, 6, 9, 8, 2, 3, "bar", "foo"]`

---

If you wal to print it differently but stays with the `HashSet` implementation,you can :

1. Use simply `StringBuilder`

   ```
   private static <T> String print(Set<T> set) {
    return "{" + set.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("@")) + "}";
   }
   ```
2. Using a `StringBuilder` to iterate and insert the `@`

   ```
   private static <T> String print(Set<T> set) {
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
       if (set.isEmpty())
           return sb.append("}").toString();

       for (T element : set) {
           sb.append(element.toString()).append("@");
       }
       sb.replace(sb.lastIndexOf("@"), sb.lastIndexOf("@") + 1, "");
       return sb.append("}").toString();
   }
   ```